# Nest can't resolve dependencies of RabbitMQService service

Tags: nestjs

I am building a nestjs app where I want to create a rabbitmq

```
@Module({
imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
        {
            name: 'rabbitmq',
            transport: Transport.RMQ,
            options: {
                urls: [
                    'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq',
                ],
                queue: 'my_queue',
            },
        },
    ]),
],
controllers: [],
providers: [RabbitMQService],
exports: [RabbitMQService],
```

})

And service:

```
@Injectable()
```

export class RabbitMQService {
constructor(
@Inject('rabbitmq') private client: ClientProxy
) {}
}

The error I am getting is: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RabbitMQService (?). Please make sure that the argument rabbitmq at index [0] is available in the RabbitMQService context.
As much I am aware, this should work, but nope. Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the code of `ClientsModule`?

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it looks like somewhere in your application you have `RabbitMQService` in an `imports` array where `@Module()` classes are supposed to go. Make sure that you keep `providers` and other `@Injectables()` to the `providers` array and keep `@Module()` and other `DynamicModule`s to the `imports` array. [Common error docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#cannot-resolve-dependency-error)